# Not able to remote desktop from my mac to windows from iphone hotspot

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, remote-desktop

Okay, first off - here are the components:

1. iPhone 6 as my Personal Hotspot
2. MacBook Pro which's connected to the Personal Hotspot
3. Windows Machine which's also connected to the Personal Hotspot

Hence, both MacBook & Windows machine should be on the same network as they're both connected to the *Personal Hotspot*. However, when I try using *Microsoft Remote Desktop* on my MacBook to connect to the Windows Machine, it says **Connection Refused**.

[image]

Here's my configuration on *MRD* if any of you were wondering:

[image]

Below is the *GW* settings as my Wifi Router (Personal Hotspot) seemed to be using that address:

[image]

How Do I resolve this?

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry. Multiple windows open & commented to wrong question. Have now deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this. It seemed *FQDN* is no more a thing. I tried putting the direct IP Address to the connection & used no gateway. It worked.

However, I am a little curious to know why MRD won't recon *Computer Name* while being on the same Network? That's what made me click to do more research. Not able to still digest a suitable answer.

In contrary to having used the personal hotspot, I started experimenting with a local vendor ISP & were assigned a static IP. I used the *Computer Name* & that worked but with personal hotspot - it didn't, I had to always use the direct IP.